# Unable to match array of objectId in aggrigate in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here in the users_application array, I have multiple ObjectIds fetched from the previous aggregate. But on ApplicationMain.aggregate function it is only showing the result of the first objecctId but not all present in the array.

the result of console.log(users_application) is [ 6061a71c0cec46307487615f, 6061a7f10cec463074876169 ]

```html
const getUserApplications = async (req, res) => {
    UserMain.aggregate([
        {$match : {"_id" : {$in : [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.profile._id)]}}},
        {$lookup : {
            from: "userapplicationdetails",
            localField: "application_details",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "applicationDetails"
        }},
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            applicationDetails: "$applicationDetails.user_applications"
        }}
    ])
    .exec((err, doc) => {
        let users_application = doc[0].applicationDetails[0];

        ApplicationMain.aggregate([
            {$match : {"_id" : { "$in" : users_application}}}, 
        ])
        .exec((err, app) =>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error: "unable to get aplications"
                })
            }
            return res.json(app[0]);
        })
    })
}
```

```html
Right now I am getting result as

{
    "applicationStatus": [
        "APPLIED"
    ],
    "project_id": [
        "6061a6b50cec463074876157"
    ],
    "project_title": [
        "temp1 "
    ]
}

expected result: 
[
{
    "applicationStatus": [
        "APPLIED"
    ],
    "project_id": [
        "6061a6b50cec463074876157"
    ],
    "project_title": [
        "temp1 "
    ]
},
{
    "applicationStatus": [
        "APPLIED"
    ],
    "project_id": [
        "6061a6b50cec463074876157"
    ],
    "project_title": [
        "temp2"
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Can you add your sample data and query https://mongoplayground.net/ and update the question with the link.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar is a nested aggregate, I dont know whether MongoDB takes nested aggregate in the query.